# Substring and charindex not returning what I expect

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to extract just the name from the comment column. However, using a combination of substring and charindex is not returning what I want.

Here is what the raw data looks like:

```
MAR-05-2018 01:08:16 PM - Joe Willis (Additional comments) text blah blah 
MAR-25-2018 01:25:19 PM - mitch.ward (Additional comments) text blah blah 
MAR-26-2018 01:33:21 PM - Hank William (Additional comments) text blah blah
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(Comment,26,CHARINDEX('(',Comment)) 
FROM ext.x_amr_sp
```

Here are my results:

```
Joe Willis (Condition Action Comments
mitch.ward (Condition Action Comments  
Hank William (Condition Action Comments
```

I want:

```
Joe Willis
mitch.ward
Hank William
```

Comment: So what's wrong? What does your data look like **before** you apply your expression? What are the results you're after?

Comment: At a total guess, mind, the parameters for `SUBSTRING` are *expression* ,*start* and ***length***, not *expression* ,*start* and *end* (which I'm guessing you think it is?).

Comment: Edited my original post for clarification

Comment: You still need to post what your data looks like **before** your attempt. We can't help you get from A to B, when we only know where B and C are.

Comment: please put 0 at the place of 26 .

Comment: I intentionally want substring to start at 26. Everything before that is garbage.

Comment: But for your sample data, @PJ.SQL position 26 onwards of `'Joe Willis (Condition Action Comments'` leaves you with `'on Comments'` How can you get the string `'Joe Willis'` from `'on Comments'`??? Like I've said twice already, we need your data ***before*** your attempts....

Comment: @Larnu edited for clarificaton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LEFT()` as

```
SELECT *, LEFT(Str, CHARINDEX('(', Str) - 2) --Here -2 t avoid the leading space
FROM (VALUES
('Joe Willis (Condition Action Comments'),
('mitch.ward (Condition Action Comments'),  
('Hank William (Condition Action Comments')
) T(Str)
```

Since you update the question and provide another data

```
SELECT *, SUBSTRING(Str, 27, CHARINDEX('(', Str) - 28)
FROM (VALUES
('MAR-05-2018 01:08:16 PM - Joe Willis (Additional comments) text blah blah'),
('MAR-25-2018 01:25:19 PM - mitch.ward (Additional comments) text blah blah'), 
('MAR-26-2018 01:33:21 PM - Hank William (Additional comments) text blah blah')
) T(Str)
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=63affdf6b91b12cf5b4d25190ca65e8e) to see how it's working.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Comment VARCHAR(1000))
INSERT @Table VALUES
('MAR-05-2018 01:08:16 PM - Joe Willis (Additional comments) text blah blah'),
('MAR-25-2018 01:25:19 PM - mitch.ward (Additional comments) text blah blah'),
('MAR-26-2018 01:33:21 PM - Hank William (Additional comments) text blah blah')

;WITH CTE (Comment) AS
(
    SELECT RIGHT(Comment, LEN(Comment)-26)
    FROM @Table
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(Comment,0, CHARINDEX('(',Comment)) FROM CTE
```

Comment: I need to skip the first 26 characters

Comment: @PJ.SQL, in that case please provide some sample data.

Comment: @Larnu It must be some top secret data.